# How to get part of file name parsed to the columnns in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Trying to use this:

```
substring(@[User::v_Filename],37,3)
```

However, it seems substring can only handle 20 characaters ?

The file name looks like this:
`D:\Projects\OTS\MYSSA Dashboard\Data\ATL_20150725Text.csv`

All I want is the `ATL` Portion

But when the ssis moves to the next file, it may change to `NYC` or `DAL`, there are about 26 files to be processed all from different regions.

Comment: There is no such limitation on substring. Maybe it's the file where you are placing the data, that has format issues.

Comment: I'm not placing the data in a file. All I'm trying to get is the 3 characters after the last backslash, or in this case the 37th character + 3. In this case ATL. Just trying to get that date from a derived column to a table. Not trying to move data into a file.

Comment: ok but how you came to the conclusion that only 20 characters are supported?

Comment: are you sure that the contents of [User::v_Filename] are as you have listed at runtime? Perhaps you could use a script component and go: system.windows.forms.messagebox.show dts.variables("User::v_filename"); to confirm this?

Comment: Yes. I can import directly, if I don't use the substring without a problem. If I use substring and say substring(@[User::v_filename],17,3) it imports but if I go 18,3 it only returns two characters....if I go over 20 like 20.3 I get an error when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Test the substring without your file variable, that uses the substring function in an expression.

Example - create a variable with the expression, then click "evaluate":

> substring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 25, 2)

It will work fine.

Given that the substring function works fine, there must be something wrong with your [User::v_Filename] variable. Are you sure it is being set correctly? Perhaps you should try running BIDS with the debugger on and a breakpoint set to right after you assign the filename, and verify that it indeed is being set correctly.

Comment: The variable had a hard coded value, but that value changes as the package runs. What if I just wanted to find the first underscore ATL_ and find the three characters before the underscore ?

Comment: If it changes you can monitor it as it runs - if you break inside the loop, you can see what the value is each time before it runs, then you can find which file is throwing the error message.